# Applet not getting initialized on the browser while using jms to connect to activemq

Tags: applet, jms, activemq-classic, appletviewer, whiteboard

I have created a java applet which acts like a whiteboard and transmits realtime coordinates using jms connected to activemq broker using Websphere application Server.

While i run the applet in applet viewer of eclipse my code runs fine and the receiving end draws the coordinates on whiteboard

when i embed the applet in a html file and try running the same through the browser i get an error "applet not initialized".
I tried running the same through the appletviewer provided  by sun (iam using linux-fedora), iam getting this error in the terminal :-

---

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:373)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:135)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:131)
    at jmspub.Pub.init(Pub.java:26)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:436)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission * read,write)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:342)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:553)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertiesAccess(SecurityManager.java:1269)
    at java.beans.PropertyEditorManager.setEditorSearchPath(PropertyEditorManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport.(IntrospectionSupport.java:57)
    ... 6 more

---

error is in this line of the code:- 
**ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");**

Please Help me find a solution....

Comment: You should state what activemq version your using.

Answer (score 0):

AccessControlExceptions are indicating this applet needs to be trusted.

OTOH this statement is suspicious.

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new 
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
```

How is that String formed?  Does it point back to the 'home' server?  If it does, the JRE seems to be confused and the applet will not need signing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ActiveMQ is trying to register a PropertyEditor which is not allowed by the applet security sandbox.  I've opened bug report [AMQ-3181](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3181).  Every thing should work fine even if the property editor does not get registered so it's  a simple case of just having to trap the exception.